# Any interval in $\Bbb{R}_\mathcal{U}$ is connected in the subspace topology.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, solution-verification, connectedness

**Problem**  Any interval in $\Bbb{R}_\mathcal{U}$ is connected in the subspace topology.

**Attempt** With the help of comments..

> First, Note that open any interval $(a,b)$ is homeomorphic with $(0,1)$.
> Define a map $f:(0,1)\to (a,b)$ by $f(x)=(b-a)x+a$. It is easy to see that $f$ is homeomorphism. So $(0,1)$ is open in the subspace topology.

> One can also go by the way
> Define a map $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to (-1,1)$ given by $f(t)=t/(1+|t|)$ is a homeomorphism, so, every open interval is connected.

> Now, we'll show that $[a,b]$ is connected as a subspace topology of $\Bbb{R}_\mathcal{U}$. Construct a map $g:\Bbb{R}\to [a,b]$
> define by $g(x)=x$ if $x\in [a,b]$, $g(x)=a$ if $x<a$ and $g(x)=b$ if $x>b$. we can see that $g$ is continuous. So the image of connected space is connected. and we're done.

> One can also think that connectedness of open interval implies connected of closed interval since $\operatorname{Cl}((a,b))=[a,b]$.

This completes the proof.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you proved if $\mathbb{R}$ or $(0,1)$ is connected?

Comment: I recently proved  $\Bbb{R}$ is connected.

Comment: If you know that, the map $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to (-1,1)$ given by $f(t)=t/(1+|t|)$ is a homeomorphism, so by your argument, every open interval is connected.

Comment: @DarthLubinus Yes.

Comment: Since the closure of $(a,b)$ is $[a,b]$, you get that every interval $(a,b]$, $[a,b)$ and $[a,b]$ is connected, so you have that every bounded interval is connected. Can you do the same for unbounded intervals?

Comment: Ok. I'll try. If i sum up your all comment then this will complete the proof.Right!

Comment: @DarthLubinus How did you get this function?

Comment: It's the odd extension of $f\colon x\in [0,\infty)\mapsto x/(x+1)\in[0,1)$. The idea behind it is that it's increasing and converges to 1, hence it's a homeomorphism. In bigger dimensions, you can use it to prove that every open ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: Can you define a function from $g:\Bbb{R}\to [0,1]$? I have a graph but I don't know how to get a function from that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110453/discussion-between-darth-lubinus-and-aman-pandey).